# Discord.py как выдать определенную роль при команде?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Мне нужно создать команду для верификации

При использовании команды участнику должна выдаться роль

Вот код:

```
@client.command()
async def верификация(ctx,self, message):
    author = ctx.author
    guild = self.get_guild(989574109606342656)
    role = guild.get_role(957124486707167262)

    await author.add_roles(role)
    await message.channel.send(f"{author.mention}Вы верифицированы!")
```

Ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in command верификация:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: self is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async def верификация(ctx,self, message)` — что такое `self`?

Если я правильно понимаю, данная команда представлена в виде отдельной функции с декоратором, то есть для бота `discord.ext.commands.Bot`, а не `discord.ext.comamnds.Cog`. Уберите `self`, вы же используете эту функцию внутри класса. Вам даже в ошибке об этом написали.

Эту строку можно заменить

```py
guild = self.get_guild(989574109606342656)
```

На эту, чтобы использовать сервер, на котором была вызвана команда, а не конкретный

```py
guild = ctx.guild
```

В остальном код верный и должен работать, если [**выданы намерения**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)